# Dataflow batch job autoscaled to only 1 worker thus too slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, datastore

Context: Trying to bulk delete some expired entities in my datastore, so used the google-provided-template here: [datastorebulkdelete](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities#datastorebulkdelete)

I have a large amount of entities to delete but seems like the job is running very slow.

Job details show it's running with only 1 worker. Is it possible to expedite? Or it's decided by the job template implementation itself?

Anyone has some idea/ insights? Much appreciated!

[Job detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DJlV.png)
[Job logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Huq.png)

Comment: Did you try the non deprecated version?

Comment: Thanks for your input guillaume - the two templates are the same one(guess google is gonna deprecate the datastore one but hasn't yet